# Constructing a rational map between two elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm grappling with a problem to construct a rational map between two elliptic curves, and I'm not seeing any way through. The problem

> Let $a,b\in K$ and put $a' = -2a$ and $b' = a^2 - 4b$. Let $E/K$ and $E'/K$ be the curves defined by the equations $y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + x$ and $y^2 = x^3 + a'x^2 + b'x$, respectively. Construct a rational map $\phi: E - - \to E'$ of degree 2, and give the associated embedding of the functions fields.

I've tried a number of different maps, picking some (fairly nice) polynomials for the images of $X$ and $Y$, but so far without success. I'm hoping this isn't a completely messy question and that there's something to grab on to, to help in constructing $\phi$, but so far no luck.

I should add, although *I* know that $E$ and $E'$ are elliptic curves, this is a course on the arithmetic of modular forms, and we have not developed any arithmetic of elliptic curves, so any solutions that *requires* some advanced material there may not work out too well (though insight would still be appreciated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, firstly, there was a typo, making it impossible :( . The first curve was supposed to be
$$ E : y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx.$$

Secondly, this becomes the decomposition of the multiplication by two isogeny. One can find both morphisms in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. Namely, one has a map
$$ \phi : E \to E'$$
given by
$$ (x,y) \mapsto \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2},\frac{y(b-x^2)}{x^2}\right),$$
and a map
$$ \hat{\phi} :E'\to E$$
given by
$$ (x,y)\mapsto \left(\frac{y^2}{4x^2}, \frac{y(b'-x^2)}{8x^2}\right).$$

He does not show they are isogenies, but this is not too difficult to see. Suppose we have elements $r,s,u,v\in K$ such that $\phi((r,s)) = (u,v)$. Then
\begin{align*}
 u^3 + a'u^2 + b'u &= u(u^2 + a'u + b')\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^2}\left(\frac{s^4}{r^4} - 2a\frac{s^2}{r^2} + a^2 - 4b\right)\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^2}\left(\frac{s^4 - 2as^2r^2 + a^2r^4 - 4br^4}{r^4}\right)\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^6}((s^2 - ar^2)^2 - 4br^4)\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^6}((r^3 + br)^2 - 4br^4)\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{as}\ (r,s)\in E/K,\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^6}(r^6 + 2br^4 + b^2r^2 - 4br^4)\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^4}(r^4 + 2br^2 + b^2 - 4br^2)\newline
                   &= \frac{s^2}{r^4}(r^2 - b)^2\newline
                   &= \left(\frac{s(r^2 - b)}{r^2}\right)^2 = v^2.
\end{align*}
So for every point (nonzero) $(r,s)$ on $E$, we see $\phi$ maps to a point of $E'$.